# Making a sorted list

Tags: python, r, excel, dictionary, pivot-table

I have been given a set of 20,000 entries in Excel.  Each entry is a string, and they are all names of events such as: `Daytona 500`, `NASCAR`, `3x1 Brand Rep`, etc.

Many of the event names are repeated, and I would like to make a list and sort them and find the most common items in the list, and how many times each one is entered.  I am half way through my first semester of Python and have just learned about lists, and would like to use Python 2.7 to do this task, but I am also open to using Excel or R if it makes more sense to use one of these.

I'm not sure where to start or how to input such a large list into a program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Excel I would use a PivotTable, about 15 seconds to set up:

[image: SO28776990 example]

Comment: Thanks! I was trying to do this with before posting but was missing the Row Labels on my excel.  My version looks a bit different than the tutorials posted, but I got it figured out now.

Answer (score 0):

```
your_list = ['Daytona 500', 'NASCAR'] # more values of course
```

Now use a dictionary comprehension to count items for each unique key.

```
your_dict = {i:your_list.count(i) for i in set(your_list)}
```

Comment: Thanks! I will try to write a program this weekend that incorporates a dictionary - seems like a good place to start!